# Empty Results from Here API for the sample zipcodes

Tags: here-api

When I do the GET Request to the here API with the below zip codes I am getting an empty list. But When I google these zip codes, I can see that they are valid.

Here is the GET Request URL: [https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=postalCode=[Insert-zip-code];country=USA&apiKey=[Insert-API-Key]](https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=postalCode=%5BInsert-zip-code%5D;country=USA&apiKey=%5BInsert-API-Key%5D)

Below are the fallowing Zip Codes:

75046
34988
68902
45258
19486
88102
32245
28603
68501
93403
68602
91365

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=postalCode=zip_code+USA&apiKey=your_api_key
Notice that there is only one `q`.

The above will work, but in some cases it will give you results not only from the United States.
Keep in mind what the API documentation says for [this service](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-geocode-address-bundle.html):

> Address lookup by postal code (SGP, IRL)
>
> ---
>
> (...) This feature is available for these two countries only.

It's only for **Ireland** and **Singapore**.

There is an [alternative for the United States](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-geocode-hpc-hsn.html) (and Netherlands), but it requires the zip+4 code.

[What is a Zip+4 Code?](http://www.mymarathoncountyaddress.org/faq/what-zip4-code-and-why-may-it-change)

> A ZIP+4 code uses the basic five-digit code plus four additional
> digits to identify a geographic segment within the five-digit delivery
> area, such as a city block, a group of apartments, an individual
> high-volume receiver of mail, a post office box, or a specific
> delivery route

Example: https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=postalCode=60606-1506&apiKey=your_api_key
Notice that there are two q's.

Comment: As you mentioned, I had tried with theURL: https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=postalCode=zip_code+USA&apiKey=your_api_key and now I am getting the results from the API with in the United states but the results are not right. For Example: If I try with 45258-0002 (which is in cincinnati: https://oh.postcodebase.com/zipcode/45258-0002) I am getting results from Missouri and also the query score is around 0.41. All the zip code's which I mentioned above are having the same problem

Comment: @sandeep-madineni remember "It's only for Ireland and Singapore".You are using the service that is for those two countries, I suppose that by not specifying one of the two, the api returns results from "all" the world. But again, that service did not work in every country. For the United States you must use the last one I put in my answer (zip+4 code). Anyway I am not specialist in Here API, my answer is based on tests I did, and what I read in the documentation. You should contact them to find a more accurate answer.